# Test if Teams is sharing a screen

Tags: windows, powershell, microsoft-teams

is there a way to find out if a screen is currently being shared in MS Teams? I couldn't find anything reliable on the Internet. I would like to query the status with PowerShell.

Comment: Run sysinternals procmon with filter "category = write" and see if any registry items or files change when sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to find out if a screen is currently being shared in Microsoft Teams using PowerShell.

Currently there is no APIs or PowerShell cmdlets available that can be used to query the status of screen sharing in a Teams meeting or call.

To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in
[Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).